# Overriding Account/context_processors.py (Pinax/Django)

Tags: python, django, pinax

I'm trying to override the default Account/context_processors.py for the Pinax project.

However, each time I try, it can't find the file and continues to use the default.

The path of the file in the default project is: pinax/apps/account/context_processors.py

I have tried placing a custom version of context_processors.py it in the following locations in my project:

1. myapp/apps/account/context_processors.py
2. myapp/account/context_processors.py
3. myapp/pinax/context_processors.py

I assumed that the first would have been the way to go.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django relies on [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) to locate and import context processor. It's a bit different from the behavior of template searching.
So override `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings file to change `"pinax.apps.account.context_processors.account"` to your import path.

Comment: Thanks okm! So I had actually tried changing that as well, but keep getting the following error: Error importing request processor module apps.account.context_processors: "No module named account.context_processors". Am I not using the correct import path?

Comment: @user1328021 keep it consistent w/ your apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Also, use `apps.account.context_processors.your_function_name` instead of `apps.account.context_processors`

Comment: Ok! Perfect. So in `INSTALLED_APPS` it was still pointing to `pinax.apps.accounts`. I changed that to just `accounts` since I saved the entire directory into my local project when modifying it and it now works properly.